# Перенаправление с помощь с htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите написать код, чтобы, набирая `название-сайта.com/название-страницы`, перебрасывало пользователя на `название-сайта.com/?название-страницы`, но в адресе у пользователя ничего не менялось. При этом не выполнять при: `название-сайта.com/?название-страницы`.

Пробовал:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /[^\?](.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://mydomen.com/\?$1 [L]
```

Comment: А зачем в последнюю строчку добавил \\ перед?

Comment: Убрал, но все-равно не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Эта ваша строка не имеет смысла... Сначала не заметил эту ошибку
# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} -f

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://mydomen.com/?$1 [L]
```

**Обновление**

[[@Minetrader](/users/24466/minetrader)](/users/24466/minetrader)

`%{QUERY_STRING}` - строка запросов (`?название-страницы`)
^ - символ начала строки.
$ - символ конца строки.
`^$` - пустая строка. Иными словами, все вместе это значит, что в URL нет части `?название-страницы`.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

Как это работает?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация.

Comment: @Minetrader, покажите код .htaccess полностью, пожалуйста.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. :-):-)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\?(.+)$ - [L] # если в начале есть ?, то ничего не делать и закончить преобразования
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://mydomen.com/?$1 [L] # если дошли до сюда, то преобразовываем
```

Comment: На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация.

Comment: Спасибо. :-)